# Do you know any good tutorial on designing EEG experiments with PsychoPy?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, software, event-related-potential

I'm trying to find good documentation on using [PsychoPy](http://www.psychopy.org/) to measure Event-Related Potentials. In particular, I want to measure and compare the amplitude of the N170, a face-sensitive ERP, when presenting neutral versus threatening faces.
I would be using the Emotiv Epoc EEG headset, [whose validity for research on the N170 has been documented](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277818124_Measuring_the_face-sensitive_N170_with_a_gaming_EEG_system_A_validation_study).

Comment: What makes you think PsychoPy is able to do this?

Comment: Well I don't know for sure that it can do exactly what I want but I do know at least two things: 1/ there is a tutorial in the book "EEG Methods for the Psychological Sciences" on how to design an "EEG experiment" in PsychoPy. I don't have this book though. 2/ There is a discussion in the PsychoPy discussion group on how to make EPOC's software work with PsychoPy and the consensus is that it "should be feasible" by sending event code via a COM port. However, I couldn't find any confirmation that it has been done.

Comment: @Seanny123, That said, I am open to any suggestion. It's possible that my solution is not very well thought out.

Comment: @Seanny123, also, there seems to be this Python library, python-emotiv, that can directly access the Emotiv Epoc EEG headset's data. Using this library in PsychoPy shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of misconceptions (Not your fault! We all need to start somewhere!), which makes this question hard to answer. PsychoPy is a Python library for creating test interfaces for psychological experiments. For example, creating a window with buttons to press. You need to use python-emotiv to get the data. As for analysing the data for ERP, that's a whole other data-based question.

Comment: @Seann123, thank you for the helpful comment. Haha, yes, I guess my question is confusing. I know PsychoPy is for creating interfaces for psychological experiments. However, I thought, perhaps mistakenly, that it allowed to record various data such as: which subject is being monitored, when the stimulus was presented, what was the response time, etc. Another assumption I am making is that PsychoPy will tell whatever library or software is used to collect EEG data when to start and stop collecting it. Anyway, do you know any good tutorial on designing EEG experiments with PsychoPy?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, but that sounds like a really awesome way to rephrase your question!

Comment: Psychopo can be easily used for presenting experimental stimuli for EEG/ERP experiments, including for N170 research. You usually send triggers to the recording computer to synchronize EEG recording and stimulus presentation.

Comment: Yes, PsychoPy can be used for administering an EEG/ERP experiment -- I've done it. However, I didn't use the Epoc system -- I used the BrainVision system.

Answer (score 2):

A collection of classic EEG experiments implemented in Python and Jupyter notebooks. 
Currently, all experiments are implemented for the Muse EEG device and using psychopy lib for stimulus presentation. 
Classification is made offline though. But I'll post very soon an online tutorial: 
https://github.com/NeuroTechX/eeg-notebooks/tree/master/notebooks

Answer (score 2):

You can buy the [book](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/building-experiments-in-psychopy/book253480#contents) in particular Chapter 18: Building an EEG study. There is also the [PsychoPy forum](https://discourse.psychopy.org/search?q=eeg) with 50+ questions about EEG. You could also go to the lead developers [OSF page](https://osf.io/tkedn/) and steal some code there from his EEG experiments.